# Rotating array from desired location using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I have a boolean array . I have tried to rotate the array using scipy.ndimage.rotate . The problem is that the array rotates from the center and I want to rotate it from desired point. The given array which I call mask in the code is an ellipsoid and for example I want to rotate it from one of the ends of the ellipsoid. How can that be possible using scipy.ndimage ?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import skimage
from skimage import draw

mask = skimage.draw.ellipsoid(10,12,16)

rotated_mask = scipy.ndimage.rotate(mask, angle1 , axes =(0,2))
```

So my question is how can I rotate the mask using scipy so that it rotates from a specific location and not just from center ?

Answer (score 0):

Try composing the rotation with a shift:

- first apply a shift to move the rotation axis to the center point,
- then apply the rotation with the parameter you want,
- last apply the opposite of the first shift.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift.html should help.

Comment: I think this will shift the array not the rotation axis. As per the answer if I shift my array to np.array([10,12,16]) which will be the center .But what is the opposite of first shift .Will I not get back the same result if I do opposite of first shift. Could you please explain . It will be nice if you could answer in the form of code.